# What is this syntax `<-` in `lodash-match-pattern`

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am looking for a library to do json match https://github.com/mjhm/lodash-match-pattern#73-map-values-transform-example.

What I don't understand is the syntax it uses like

```
var extraFancyResult = matchPattern(realTestData, `{
  name: /^[A-Z]\w+$/,
  email: _.isEmail,
  age: _.isBetween|20|30,
  friends: {
    <-.filterPattern|'{age: _.isBetween|20|30 ...}': _.isSize|2,
    <=.get|name: [
      'Breeze',
      ...
    ]
  }
}`);
```

The confusion part for me is `<-.` `<=.` used in `matchPattern`:

```
<-.filterPattern|'{age: _.isBetween|20|30 ...}': _.isSize|2,
    <=.get|name: [
      'Breeze',
      ...
    ]
```

what kind of syntax it uses?

Comment: "*Here `<=.get|email` says that `_.get(..., 'email')` is applied to each of the entries of the `joeUser.friends` array and creates a new array*" from the link you posted

Comment: it says: The <= says that the pattern is applied to each of the entries of the joeUser.friends array. In contrast, the <- operator would say that the pattern is matched against the array as a whole.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Where can I find the definition for this? Is it regex syntax or something else?

Comment: "*Where can I find the definition for this?*" literally from the link you posted. It's the first sentence under the code block. "*Is it regex syntax*" no, it's not